# Automatically inherit arrow function parameter types

Tags: typescript, types

If I supply an arrow function as an argument in TSX:

```
<Form.Control
    onChange={event => /** do something **/}
/>
```

TypeScript warns me that the `event` parameter in my arrow function implicitly has type `any`, because I have not declared the type.

I do not want it to be `any`. I would also prefer not to write out the long and cumbersome type `FormEvent<ReplaceProps<"input", BsPrefixProps<"input"> & FormControlProps>>` which apparently is the type of `event` as given by React Bootstrap in the above case.

How can I *inherit* the type automatically? Is there something like:

```
<Form.Control
    onChange={(event: inherit) => /** do something **/}
/>
```

Comment: I think you'd be good just by using FormControlProps? And from typescript perspective, you are creating a new object and you are responsible of defining its type. How typescript would now a newly created function's argument's type?

Comment: This is called contextual typing, and it should happen if `onChange` is correctly defined. Where is `Form.Control` defined ?

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı What do you mean by `using FormControlProps`? I need to define the type of `event` in my callback, what should I declare as its type so that the compiler is satisfied and the code works? I need the exact same type that is given from `FormControl` to the `onChange` callback. In `FormControlProps` it is defined as `onChange?: React.FormEventHandler<this>;`, but using it this way won't work.

Comment: Please consider editing the code here to constitute a [mcve] so that someone can easily see the problem in a standalone TypeScript IDE, and/or provide a link to the code in a web IDE so that the problem can be demonstrated.  Good luck!